# Register script reference tag just before end of body tag

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way to register a script reference just before end of body tag? I've just tried:

```
page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("jquery.widgets.js", page.ResolveClientUrl("~/js/plugins/jquery.widgets.js"));
```

but it registers the file just after ViewState, at the beginning of form element.

Comment: Are you trying to do this dynamically or just find the best way to add scripts and script references at the bottom of the page in ASP.NET?

Comment: Best way to add scripts and script references at the bottom of the page in ASP.NET

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a script manager to register scripts dynamically at  `Page_Load` use the `LoadScriptsBeforeUI="False"` attribute to ensure the scripts are registered at the end of the document.

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    Some content here
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="smScriptManager" LoadScriptsBeforeUI="False">
        <Scripts>

        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
</form>
```

And then in your code

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    smScriptManager.Scripts.Add(New ScriptReference("~/Include/Site.js"))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 6):

What I do is create a ContentPlaceHolder at the bottom of the MasterPage (if you have one)-

```
//Any scripts required on all pages, e.g. JQuery go before the content placeholder

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ScriptContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</body>
```

In the individual page I will then have-

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="ScriptContentPlaceHolder" ID="PageScriptContent" runat="server">
     //Load script with application relative path
     <script src="<%= Page.ResolveURL("~/js/plugins/jquery.widgets.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>

     //Load script with HTML relative path
     <script src="/js/plugins/jquery.widgets.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</asp:Content>
```

If you did need to conditionally add a script from the code behind you could add a new literal or [HtmlGenericControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlgenericcontrol.aspx) to the ContentPlaceHolder using [Controls.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.controls%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

```
 HtmlGenericControl ScriptGenericControl = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
 ScriptGenericControl.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript");
 ScriptGenericControl.Attributes.Add("src", Page.ResolveURL("~/js/plugins/jquery.widgets.js"));
 PageScriptContent.Controls.Add(ScriptGenericControl);
```

Or-

```
 PageScriptContent.Controls.Add(new Literal(){ Text = string.Format("<script type='text/javascript' src='{0}'></script>", Page.ResolveURL("~/js/plugins/jquery.widgets.js")) };
```