# ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript is placing script inside the <head>

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I am most certainly not understanding something about this.  I have been googling around for about 3 hours, attempting different ways of dynamically adding a call to a javascript function from the vb code-behind.  Every answer I read is explaining the difference between `RegisterStartupScript` and `RegisterClientScriptBlock` is that the StartupScript places the script at the bottom of the page (what I want) and the ClientScriptBlock places the script in the `<head>`.

Unfortunately for me, the below code places the script in the `<head>`.  I have tried the ClientScriptBlock as well to the same end.  I expect that I am just overlooking something...

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Me.GetType(), "test", "openVendorForm();", True)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does the `<head>` element have the `runat="server"` attribute? Does your page have a `<form runat="server">` element? (Note: I'm not implying you should or shouldn't in either case; I'm just trying to get some info that might be helpful.)

Comment: @MichaelLiu Yes, it is using a master page which has both a `<head runat="server">` and a `<form runat="server">`

Comment: Perhaps try [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333249/register-script-reference-tag-just-before-end-of-body-tag)

Comment: Please post the content of the `<head>` element when you view the page source in the browser.

Comment: @TimVermaelen Thanks for the link, but I attempted adding the `LoadScriptsBeforeUI="false"` and it didn't seem to change anything (even tried closing IE and killing the iisexpress instance)

Comment: @MichaelLiu There is a TON of code in the header when I view the source...  Perhaps a screenshot with all the scripts collapsed will suffice?  http://i.imgur.com/bRjwKT7.png  If not, let me know...

Comment: I wanted to see the location of the script relative to other scripts in the `<head>`. It's important though to look at the actual page source (View > Source), not the DOM view.